# Delete entries from multiple tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables in my postgreSQL

item_table:

```
id  item_id
------------
1   1234
2   5678
```

account_table:

```
item_id     account_id
----------------------
2       abcd
```

payment_table:

```
account_id  payment_status
--------------------------
abcd        good
```

Description

1. *item_id* in the *account_table* is the *id* of *item_table*
2. *account_id* of the *payment_table* is the *account_id* of *account_table*

I want to delete the entry from all tables associated with *item_id* from the *item_table*

Example : If my item_id is 5678 then I want to delete entries from all tables in which the ids are connected to each other.

How to achieve this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

If account.item_id is declared as a foreign key to item.id, you might declare that foreign key as 'ON DELETE CASCADE'. Then deleting a row from 'item' would cascade the deletion 'account'.

Repeat as needed for other tables.

It could be I've misunderstood you, but it's easy enough for you to test.

Comment: None of these tables are connected to each other using foreign key. Is there a solution in that case?

Comment: @SravanJS: Worst case, run one DELETE statement per table, probably wrapped in a transaction. Wrap *that* in a function.

Comment: Tables are not connected by FK. Is there a solution in this case? Yes, **add the missing FKs**. Without them you have data integrity issues - meaning bad data.  After all with the values posted what the value of a row in `payment` table with account_id =' xyz', or  an `account`  table row with item_id = 42? They are just wrong and can generate correct but invalid/misleading results. FK would prevent them from being in the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to delete from three tables then you need to run three DELETE statements:

```
delete from payment_table
where account_id in (select account_id
                     from account_table
                     where item_id in (select id 
                                       from item_table
                                       where item_id = 5678));

delete from account_table
where item_id in (select id 
                  from item_table
                  where item_id = 5678);

delete from item_table
where item_id = 5678;
```